# String array gets passed to my controller as just a string when there is only one element

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs, groovy

When I have multiple elements in the array it passes an array into my controller. But if there is only one element in the array it passes it to the controller as a string not as a string array.

**javascript.js**

```
var idArray = [];
idArray.push('testString');

Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: '/mark/fetch',
  params: {array: idArray}
});
```

**markController.groovy**

```
def fetch = {
  def idArray = params.array
  idArray.each{
    print it
  }
}
```

So `print it` prints each letter of testString instead of the whole string at one time.

How can I make sure that idArray always gets passed into the controller as an array?

Comment: Is this a Grails controller since you are using params? If it is, can you try using `params.list('array')` instead?

Comment: @dmahapatro this is exactly what I was looking for, make it an answer and I'll accept it, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you were referring to Grails controller as you are using `params` you can try using `params.list('array')` instead.

This nature of `params` is explained [here as Type Conversion](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#typeConverters).

Answer (score 1):

They are sent as string in both case. That's your framework that decodes the comma separated value list which results of the casting of the array to a string (try `idArray.toString()`). It probably does that based on the `Content-Type` header of the request.

You can try to use the [`jsonData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection-method-request) option of the request instead of `params`. If your framework accepts JSON, the typing of the data will be better respected.